# Using "volume" argument in ffmpeg volume audio filter

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, volume

I wish to "silence" the background noise in an audio, without removing the silence entirely - so as to keep the length of the audio constant. I am trying to use `volume` filter in `ffmpeg` like

`ffmpeg -i input.flac -filter:a "volume='if(lt(volume,-8dB),0,1)':eval=frame" output.flac`

but this seems to output the same file as input. I checked this by seeing the `volumedetect` output and it is identical for `input.flac` and `output.flac`.

I am new to `ffmpeg` so sorry if this is preliminary; quick help or pointers to relevant examples appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The volume filter does not detect the volume level of the input. See the [agate](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#agate) filter instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gyan; that worked like a charm!